# Is there any reason for me to sleep?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion I'd sleep to level up, but that's no longer necessary.

Is there any benefit to sleeping in Skyrim?  Will my character get tired?

Comment: I thought everyone has played Fallout 3 or New Vegas. Most things in Skyrim work exactly like in Fallout. A surprising amount of gamers on youtube are completely lost when it comes to Skyrim even though they have played through Fallout not long ago... But I guess that's a way to weed out the.. weeds... :P

Comment: No, you should just keep playing so that you can be the first one to reach... Oh wait, you were asking about your character sleeping.  Never mind.

Comment: @TorValamo Although I played Fallout 3 (though not New Vegas) I only started playing Oblivion earlier this year, I don't even remember how it worked in Fallout 3 to be honest :)

Comment: If you are a werewolf then no.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping) wiki:

> Sleeping is the process of resting in a bed, sleeping bag/roll, pile of hay to fully restore your health, magicka, and stamina. In addition, sleeping in a good bed gives a temporary bonus to magicka and health. Beds in player-owned houses provide better bonuses than other beds. If you sleep long enough in any bed, you will receive the "Well Rested" bonus which increases the speed of skill mastery by 10% for the next 8 hours. If you sleep near to your spouse (same building/cell), upon waking you will receive a "Lover's Comfort" bonus which increases speed of skill mastery by 15% for 8 hours. This effect can be duplicated by The Lover Stone which confers this bonus for as long as the stone is the player's active symbol.

Also keep in mind that, as alluded to by [ryanzec's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35950/12936), there is at least one quest that requires you to sleep in a bed to initiate it, so even werewolves have a reason to sleep at least once (after killing Grelod the Kind and receiving the courier message from the Dark Brotherhood).

Comment: I love that marriage has some perks. Very cool.

Comment: @spugsley You can even get your spouse to cook for you!

Comment: That must be some sort of super power.

Comment: @Akrive - Excellent! Gonna go tell him to make me a sandwich :)

Comment: Do note that someone with beast-blood (werewolf power) cannot gain any bonuses from resting.

Comment: @spugsley Unlike real life.

Comment: @spugsley If they don't want to make you one, remember to sudo!

Comment: This information is not entirely correct. There are three relevant bonuses: Rested, from sleeping in any bed, bedroll, etc. Well Rested, from sleeping in any bed you own, e.g. in your own house, in an inn you paid for, etc. Lover's Comfort, for sleeping with your spouse. For the next 8 hours, they give you respectively 5%, 10%, and 15% bonus to skill levelling. The wiki page you link has been updated to include more of this information, but seems to forget about the Rested (5%) bonus.

Comment: Any idea as to how long those 8 hours are in real time? I seem to lose the bonus every time i fast travel.

Comment: Is it 8 hours our time or 8 hours real time

Answer (score 32):

You get bonus when you are rested.

I read somewhere that it is an increase to learning all abilities for 8 hours

- 5% for any bed.
- 10% for a rented or owned bed.
- 15% for sleeping next to your husband/wife.

To be confirmed still. Maybe it appears in the spell menu "Active"? Did not checked.

Comment: It does appear in the Active Effects list.

Comment: Rested, Well Rested, Lover's Comfort

Comment: It should be noted (as others have, it seems) these bonuses are not available to werewolves, and Lover's Comfort does not stack with Lover's Stone.

Answer (score 13):

The dark Brotherhood quest might need you to sleep in a bed instead of just rest.

Comment: I also found myself unable to use any world tool (forge, alchemy table, arcane enchanter, etc.) whilst the game was waiting for me to go sleep to trigger this quest. Sleeping (and thus starting the quest) fixed this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Some quests are just doable at a certain time.
If you don't want to wait you can reach them best by sleeping.

Comment: For this purpose, waiting and sleeping are effectively the *exact same thing* - especially if you're a werewolf.  So, this really doesn't provide a good reason to sleep.